# Query for retrieving list of items based on two different lists

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Problem: Searching employees based on document numbers.
Input: List of document nos. and document types
Expected result: list of employees for corresponding document nos **AND** types.

tables I have:

Table 1:employee
empID  - person

Table 2:document 
docNo  - docType - id

Please note: employee.person.id = doc.parent.id - this is true by database design
Wrote the query like:

```
SELECT employee 
from Employee employee, Document doc 
WHERE doc.docType IN :docTypeList 
and doc.docNo IN :docNoList 
and employee.person.id = doc.parent.id
```

I know it wont work, because of "doc.docType IN :docTypeList and doc.docNo IN :docNoList", but couldn't think alternative. Any leads to modify the query so that I can handle both docTypeList and docNoList to find employees that matches both of them.

Comment: Friends and Tables 'JOIN' together.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to join the tables on the ID value and add the right values in your select clause:

```
SELECT a.employee, b.docType, b.docNo
FROM employee a JOIN document b
ON a.empID=b.id
```

here is an example using the naming conventions(sort of) you have in your original question:

```
SELECT emp.employee, doc.docType, doc.docNo
FROM Employee emp JOIN document doc
ON emp.empID=doc.id
```

Unrelated to your question but when using tablename aliases you should probably shorten the alias otherwise you can just type out the name of the table everytime. The point of an alias is to make your code cleaner and easier to type by using shortened tablenames. See above - I changed employee alias to "emp"

Answer (score 0):

I'm more SQL server so presuming your list parameters are like tableTypes....

```
SELECT employee 
from Employee employee
INNER JOIN Document doc ON doc.parent.id = employee.person.id
WHERE 
doc.docType IN ( Select doctype FROM :docTypeList )
and doc.docNo IN (Select doc no FROM :docNoList )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass a list of parameters to IN(), the solution is to break down your list and pass each item as a separate parameter to the SQL statement.

Assuming MySQL + PDO:

```
$paramCount = 0;
$params = [];  // holds parameter values
$typesParamNames = $numbersParamNames = []; // parameter names for each list

// document types
foreach ($docTypeList as $val)
{
    ++$paramCount;
    $paramName = ":p{$paramCount}";
    $params[$paramName] = $val;
    $typesParamNames[] = $paramName;
}

// document numbers
foreach ($docNoList as $val)
{
    ++$paramCount;
    $paramName = ":p{$paramCount}";
    $params[$paramName] = $val;
    $numbersParamNames[] = $paramName;
}

// build the SQL
$typesSqlFragment = implode(',', $typesParamNames);
$numbersSqlFragment = implode(',', $numbersParamNames);
$sql = "SELECT employee from Employee employee, Document doc WHERE doc.docType IN ($typesSqlFragment) and doc.docNo IN ($numbersSqlFragment) and employee.person.id = doc.parent.id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// pass the collected parameters values to the prepared statement
foreach ($params as $name => $val) {
    $stmt->bindParam($name, $val);
}

// run it
$stmt->execute();
```